# Using `into_iter` with containers behind mutable reference

Tags: rust

iI am struggling to understand a particular instance of an ownership rule in Rust, particularly as I believe the example should compile when it does not.

I have something like this:

```
pub struct Structure {
    pub collection1: VecDeque<something>,
    pub collection2: VecDeque<something_else>,
}

impl Structure {

    pub fn my_function(&mut self) {

        for thing in self.collection1.into_iter() { // create consuming iterator
            // do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

This example paraphrases the actual production code I am working with but I believe this is enough to show the problem.

The compiler produces this error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.collection1` which is behind a mutable reference
```

I don't understand why exactly this is the case or what can be done about it.

Thinking about this, without considering ownership rules, as if we were in any other language (Hint: Maybe C++) we would come to this conclusion:

`for thing in self.collection1.into_iter()` consumes the `VecDeque`, and at the end of the function call `self.collection1` is just empty.

This is the behaviour I want to achieve, and it feels like it should be a common thing to want to do and should be possible.

Thinking about things in terms of Rust ownership:

I would guess that `collection1.into_iter()` transfers ownership of (moves) `collection1`. Since we are operating on `self` with a reference, clearly we can't move part of it, regardless of the mutability.

So then there should perhaps be a way to "swap" (again: thinking like C++) the contents of `collection1` with a new `VecDeque` which we can create at the start of `my_function`. But I don't know how to do that. I tried de-structuring `self` and then setting `self` to a new instance of `Structure`. This didn't compile.

At the end of the function call I want to replace `self.collection1` with something else. This strongly suggests that I should somehow be able to move out the contents of `self.collection1` and replace or re-assign it with some new thing.

Here's a sketch of how that might look like.

```
pub fn my_function(&mut self) {

    let tmp = self.collection1;
    self.collection1 = VecDeque::new();
    for thing in collection1.into_iter() {
        self.collection1.push_back(thing);
    }
}
```

With this in mind, it's obvious this should compile into something sensible. But I don't know exactly how to do it. Perhaps I am missing something obvious?

---

While researching this question, I discovered that I can use `std::mem::take` or `std::mem::replace` to find a workable solution - but the questions still stands. Why *doesn't* the above work, when it seems intuitive that it should?

Here are those examples which do compile:

```
pub fn my_function(&mut self) {

    // replaces self.collection1 with default value, ie: empty container
    let tmp = std::mem::take(&mut self.collection1);

    self.collection1 = VecDeque::new();
    for thing in collection1.into_iter() {
        self.collection1.push_back(thing);
    }
}
```

```
// This also works

// replaces self.collection1 with something else
let tmp = std::mem::replace(&mut self.collection1, VecDeque::new());
```

I believe `std::mem::swap` should also work, but I couldn't get this to compile:

```
let tmp = VecDeque::new();
std::mem::swap(self.collection1, tmp); // does not compile ? why ?
```

Answer (score 3):

What you describe is called [`drain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html#method.drain) in Rust.

```rust
pub struct Structure {
    pub collection1: VecDeque<something>,
}

impl Structure {

    pub fn my_function(&mut self) {
        for element in self.collection1.drain(..) {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Which can easily be found by looking through the methods on `VecDeque` ...

The problem with your second example is simply that this line:

```rust
let tmp = self.collection1;
```

is not allowed, and I don't see why it should be, if you want to exchange the value in `collection1` you can use the functions you already found, so any complex compiler logic is just wasted. It's also obfuscating the `swap` you're doing.

Rust often tends to be explicit rather than implicit in many places, this is one of them.

---

> ```rust
> std::mem::swap(self.collection1, tmp); // does not compile ? why ?
> ```

doesn't compile because you're not giving mutable references to `swap` (same reason your `take` and `remove` examples don't work either, among more issues) try

```rust
std::mem::swap(&mut self.collection1, &mut tmp);
```

Comment: The `take` and `remove` examples do work? Or at least they should do. I will double check

Comment: No you are right, it should have `&mut` - I've update it